# Жёлтый vs желтенький

Tags: значения

в чем разница между жёлтый и жёлтенький?

Comment: приблизительно в том же, в чём разница между "красный" и "красненький".

Comment: in English we don't have diminutives for colors, so I was glad to find this thread with an explanation.  But then... there are 4 different answers and they all contradict each other.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

The difference is the attitude of the speaker towards the color. While *жёлтый* is neutral, the speaker has no special feelings or attitude towards the object being that yellow, calling an object *желтенький* shows the speaker is not indifferent to the yellow of the object, the color seems somehow unusual, out-of-place, either too bright, too yellow, or not suitable for that object to be taken seriously.

On the other hand, *желтенький* can be used without any attitude connotations by children or young mothers who tend to use diminutive forms of every word, "horsy/horsie, doggy, birdy" style. In Russian, not only nouns and adjectives but even verbs can have diminutive forms, like «А вот вы что с утра любите *покушенькать*?», 'And what do you like to eat in the morning?'

Comment: Just a note to @1453 - please never ever actually use "покушенькать". It's one of the worst abominations of a word I've seen.

Comment: а возможно делать это с любым глаголом? —например, "я читенькаю". это было бы классно)) хаха

Comment: @VCH250: https://google.ru/search?q=читатеньки , https://google.ru/search?q=читатенькать Or maybe you meant the loanword *читить* ("to cheat, as in a video game")? What you said would be the 1st sg. diminutive for it, for sure.

Comment: I would add "[пойдём] спатоньки". Disgusting, nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

One more meaning of "жёлтенький": it can refer to close shades of yellow, something like "yellowish". 
Added: for example, if I am (informally) asked which of those button to click, my gut instinct is to answer "жёлтенькую". If I answer "жёлтую", I might get an odd look because there's no yellow button and the first one is beige or whatever. 
. 
[image: two awful buttons]
But agreed with Quassnoi♦, "желтоватый" is a more correct term here. It's just a bit longer to pronounce.

Comment: I think "yellowish" would rather be *желтоватый*. Could you please provide an example where mere replacement of *жёлтенький* with *жёлтый* or vice versa would assume a change of shade?

Answer (score 1):

Никакой разницы в цвете нет, вся разница в объекте, о котором идёт речь: если к нему применяется уменьшительно-ласкательное, его можно распространить и на прилагательное.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд слово желтенький, как и вообще прилагательные с суффиксом "еньк" не несет в себе никакого грамматического смысла, и используется по какой-то непонятной причине в лексиконе женщин. Если нужно словами передать блеклый оттенок желтого цвета то правильно будет сказать "желтоватый", но уж никак не "желтенький".

Однако есть некоторые устоявшиеся слова с суффиксом "еньк", например: 
маленький, старенький.

Comment: If a word is used on a daily basis by a signification fraction of speakers, it for sure carries some kind of grammatical load. You can say the word is not normative or fit for a certain environment, but not that it isn't "right": people say and understand it, after all.

Comment: @Quassnoi In case of "желтенький" I would tend to say it is incorrect and even among women such word would be rare. Would be probably common only among those with strong speech travesty habits. For a learner, I would recommend to avoid this in general.

Comment: Russian authors like Ostrovsky, Prishvin and Saltykov-Schedrin deemed this word correct (and appropriate enough) to use it in their works. Their style does not strike me as feminine

Comment: @Quassnoi ну "подруженьки", "хорошенький" еще можно как-то понять. Но "желтенький" или "мокренький" не укладывается у меня в голове да и противно звучит.